# Dropdown width too large

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 4 Select Picker to define my dropdown. However, the width of the dropdown is automatically set to the width of the largest text. **Is there a way to manually set this width**? Here is what I have so far:

```
<span> <select class="selectpicker" style="width: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;position: absolute;"
multiple data-live-search="true" 
data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count" 
data-size="15">

<?php


  $db = $_POST["dbsel"]=="" ? "pdbbind" : $_REQUEST["dbsel"];

  $metSel = "";
  $ddList = "";

  if(strcmp($db,"pdbbind")==0){
    $sql .= "SELECT DISTINCT PDBcode FROM pdbbind";
  }elseif(strcmp($db,"pdb")==0){
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT metaboliteName FROM PDB";
  }elseif (strcmp($db,"brenda")==0) {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT metaboliteName FROM BRENDA";
  }elseif (strcmp($db,"HMDB")==0) {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT metaboliteName FROM HMDB";
  }


  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";
  }

?>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by setting the max-width of the inner element style:

```
.inner {
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314713/5211833) did not work for me, below is what I had to do. Changing the width of the .inner element did not adjust the width of the dropdown menu, just the inner element. This pushed the text and scrollbar over but still left a background that is caused by the parent element of inner.

```
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu {
  width: 350px;
  min-width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding an answer. Do read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.